# For an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, does the union of the basis of the row space and null space of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ span the row space of some $m\times n$ matrix $A$, and $\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ span the null space of $A$, I think while the union of the two subspaces is not necessarily a vector space, however, if I just take the union of the basis of the two subspaces, is it correct that I now have $n$ independent vectors and hence this set would span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. In particular, the row space and null space are orthogonal complements to each other.  This is sometimes called (part of) the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra).

Comment: Of course one has to consider the row space as the column space of the transpose.

Comment: @egreg is there another way to consider the row space?

Comment: It could just be a subspace of the $m\times 1$ matrices.